# SQL statement with user defined type produces error

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-types

I have created a user defined type called `membertypes` which consists of one column of type `int` called `membertype`,

I have a stored procedure like so:

```
        declare @membertypes dbo.MemberTypes;
        INSERT INTO @membertypes VALUES (1);
        INSERT INTO @membertypes VALUES (3);

        declare @membertypecount int = (select count(1) from @membertypes)

        select username, MiniThumbNail, userID,
        from members
        where members.membertype in (case when @membertypecount > 0 then (select membertype from @membertypes) else members.membertype end)
```

It doesn't work, I get the error message:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

However, if I change the code to this it does work: -

```
        declare @membertypes dbo.MemberTypes;
        INSERT INTO @membertypes VALUES (1);
        INSERT INTO @membertypes VALUES (3);

        select username, MiniThumbNail, userID,
        from members
        where members.membertype in (select membertype from @membertypes)
```

Why does the original code produce that error?

Comment: @CaiusJard Okay but why does it work in the second piece of code?

Comment: Sorry, i've been focusing on explaining using `=` as an example, when I should have been focusing on `when the subquery is used as an expression`, but the reasoning is the same: `CASE WHEN x THEN y`  can only be used to return a single value as Y. Putting a query that returns more than one value cannot work. If the subquery was `SELECT MAX` or `SELECT TOP 1` then SQLserver would let it go

Comment: @CaiusJardbut I'm using the 'in' statement, so surely it's designed to handle more than one result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your logic:

```
   where members.membertype in (case when @membertypecount > 0 
                                     then (select membertype from @membertypes)
                                     else members.membertype 
                                 end)
```

You are misunderstanding what `case` expressions are.  A `case` expression is an expression that returns a single, scalar value.  A "scalar" value has a simple type, such as an integer or string.  (Some databases extend this to include tuples and arrays, but SQL Server is not one of them.)  Other examples of expressions are arithmetic (`'1 + 1'`), functions (`len('abc')`), and even simple columns.

Subqueries are not simple.

Happily what you want to do is easy without `case`:

```
where members.membertype in (select membertype from @membertypes) or
      not exists (select 1 from @membertypes)
```

Answer (score 0):

`case` expression would return only one value with single row, while sub-query may have multi rows. So, case expression won't work

So, You can use `left join` instead :

```
select username, MiniThumbNail, userID 
from members mb left join
     @membertypes mt
     on mt.membertype = mb.membertype
where (@membertypecount = 0 or mt.membertype is not null);
```

Comment: Note that providing something that works isn't an anwer to *this* particular question; he already has something that works (`IN`), he wants to know why using `=` doesn't work

Comment: @CaiusJard. . . `True`. But, `IN` would not do that might not `OP` want. `IN` would filtered only matching rows, if not query will return no row.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the original code produce that error?

This is invalid:

```
case when @membertypecount > 0 then (select membertype from @membertypes) else members.membertype end
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In a `CASE WHEN x THEN y` the `y` must represent a single value like `1`, `'apple'` etc. It's not valid to have a CASE WHEN choose between one of several sets of data to feed into an IN.